# serialize imageList property

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, imagelist

I have an Album class which contains title, description and an integer value of the index of a cover image. It also contains an imageList.

I need to serialize this obj and while the imageList is not serializeable but the imageListStream is...

I'm a complete c# noob so would appreciate what ever guidance available.

The desired result would be somethings like:

```
<Album>
    <Title>Album Title</Title>
    <Description>Some explanation.</Description>
    <CoverImgIndx>2</CoverImgIdx>
    <Images>
        <Image>
            <indx>0</indx>
            <filepath>"C:\Images\file1.jpg"</filepath>
        </Image>
        <Image>
            <indx>1</indx>
            <filepath>"C:\Images\file2.png"</filepath>
        </Image>
        <Image>
            <indx>2</indx>
            <filepath>"C:\Images\file3.jpg"</filepath>
        </Image>
        <Image>
            <indx>3</indx>
            <filepath>"C:\Images\file4.bmp"</filepath>
        </Image>
    </Images>
</Album>
```

obviously I need to reconstitute the imageList when deserializing...

Comment: Could you also post the definition of the class?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to use the XmlSerializer class to serialize your Album class into XML.

Something like this should work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yE8RAl

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can define your Album / Image like this:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Image")]
public class ImageSerializationContainer
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "indx")]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "filepath")]
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
[XmlType(TypeName = "Album")]
public class AlbumSerializationContainer
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CoverImgIndx { get; set; }
    public List<ImageSerializationContainer> Images { get; set; }
}
```

And then use `XmlSerializer` like this:

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AlbumSerializationContainer));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ser.Serialize(sw, yourObjectToSerialize);
return sw.ToString();
```

However I'm guessing that what you really want is to somehow convert your existing class in a form that you can serialize.

Unfortunately you don't give a lot to go on in your question, so I have to make some assumptions. Now, some of this assumptions are bound to be wrong, but that's to be expected with the level of information you have provided.

I'm going to assume that you are using the [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class and that the filenames that you have in your example are stored in a string array that is attached to the ImageList [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Feel free to modify the code to take this value from elsewhere. You did not give information about how you structure your index values. I'm assuming these are [indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz38zyat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the [ImageList.Images collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

There are several ways to approach your problem. I'm going to show you how to use [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) to convert what could be your class to a class that you can serialize and then serialize it.

Below you can find a complete example. Please note that you might need to update the AutoMapper configuration if your classes are different from presented below.

I'm demonstrating both: serializing an class to XML (example 1) and converting another class to serializable class (example 2).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AutoMapper;

namespace SO24174411
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            AlbumSerializationContainer example1 = new AlbumSerializationContainer
            {
                CoverImgIndx = 2,
                Description = "Some explanation.",
                Images = new List<ImageSerializationContainer>
                {
                    new ImageSerializationContainer {FilePath = @"C:\Images\file1.jpg", Index = 0},
                    new ImageSerializationContainer {FilePath = @"C:\Images\file2.png", Index = 1},
                    new ImageSerializationContainer {FilePath = @"C:\Images\file3.jpg", Index = 2},
                    new ImageSerializationContainer {FilePath = @"C:\Images\file4.bmp", Index = 3}
                },
                Title = "Album Title"
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Example 1");
            Console.WriteLine(Serialize(example1));

            Album album = new Album
            {
                CoverImgIndx = 2,
                Description = "Some explanation.",
                Images = new ImageList(),
                Title = "Album Title"
            };
            SetImages(album.Images, new[]
            {
                @"C:\Images\file1.jpg", 
                @"C:\Images\file1.jpg", 
                @"C:\Images\file2.png", 
                @"C:\Images\file4.bmp"
            });

            var example2 = PerformMapping(album);
            Console.WriteLine("Example 2");
            Console.WriteLine(Serialize(example2));

        }

        private static AlbumSerializationContainer PerformMapping(Album album)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Album, AlbumSerializationContainer>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ImageList, List<ImageSerializationContainer>>().ConvertUsing<ImageListconverter>();
            AlbumSerializationContainer example2 = Mapper.Map<AlbumSerializationContainer>(album);
            return example2;
        }

        public class ImageListconverter : TypeConverter<ImageList, List<ImageSerializationContainer>>
        {
            protected override List<ImageSerializationContainer> ConvertCore(ImageList source)
            {
                if (source == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                List<ImageSerializationContainer> result = new List<ImageSerializationContainer>();
                for (int i = 0; i < source.Images.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Add(new ImageSerializationContainer { FilePath = ((string[])source.Tag)[i], Index = i });
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static string Serialize(AlbumSerializationContainer a)
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AlbumSerializationContainer));
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            ser.Serialize(sw, a);
            return sw.ToString();
        }

        public static void SetImages(ImageList l, string[] names)
        {
            l.Tag = names;
            for(int i=0;i<names.Length;i++)
            {
                // Aparently you can read names[i] file here if you want
                l.Images.Add(new Bitmap(1, 1));
            }
        }
    }


    public class Album
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CoverImgIndx { get; set; }
        public ImageList Images { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlType(TypeName = "Image")]
    public class ImageSerializationContainer
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "indx")]
        public int Index { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "filepath")]
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlType(TypeName = "Album")]
    public class AlbumSerializationContainer
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CoverImgIndx { get; set; }
        public List<ImageSerializationContainer> Images { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You will be able to easily de-serialize your xml back to the serialization container class with [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Some more work will be required to map these back to your required class. Since this part depends more than any other on the information you have not provided I leave it as an exercise for the reader.